# Bootanimation.zip location on emulator

Tags: boot-animation

I am not finding Bootanimation.zip file on Android emulator 2.3.3. I have checked all below paths.

system/media or system/customize/resource or data/local.

I need to put Bootanimation.zip in right location of emulator and test

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

system/media   and /data/local/  are the right places.
The latter is preferable as it makes it easier to modify, and does not require the tedious 
modification of the system.img (system partition) size.
Note that bootanimation.zip should be lowercase, and -0 compressed.